# Unable to install Volta on WSL - ELF not found

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, volta

I am unable to install [volta](https://docs.volta.sh/guide/getting-started) as per its recommended command `curl https://get.volta.sh | bash` on WSL.

I keep getting this error. And I have no idea what it means.

[image]

Comment: If it's system installation, should you use `| sudo bash`, instead of `| bash` ?

Comment: @Philippe it's not an issue of permission (I've tried it as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer.

Not sure why exactly, but it turns out my Ubuntu WSL was still on WSL 1, not 2. Updating it solved the problem.